# Trying to use Firebase MLKit barcode scanner, "Waiting for the barcode detection module to be downloaded, please wait" appears on emulator screen

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner

I am trying to make a barcode scanner using Java and MLKit in Android Studio, but keep getting this message when I run the app in the emulator. I have an internet connection and I have tried clearing the emulated device's data. Running the emulation on a Pixel 2 XL API 29.

Can provide code if needed, but there are no errors in my code currently. I followed a tutorial line for line but for some reason cannot get it to work.

Messages in Run:

```
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite:2702

Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite, version >= 2702

V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils

I/Vision: Loading library libbarhopper.so

I/Vision: libbarhopper.so library load status: false

I/Vision: Request download for engine barcode is a no-op because rate limiting

W/ample.scannerv: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;>getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)

W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.vision.dynamite.barcode not found.
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that if you use `com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning`, the necessary data will be bundled with your app and doesn't need to be downloaded.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm... MLKit barcode scanner needs for sure real device with a camera. I'm quite sure it is useless to try to test app with an emulator.

Comment: _"MLKit barcode scanner needs for sure real device with a camera"_. Why? You need to pass it an image, but where that image comes from doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, but barcode scanning uses also device positions, so it knows angles what to expect from barcode. You must emulate all those things in the emulator to get some hope to be possible to test algorithm.  Are you sure that you know all what must be emulated and are you sure that you have done emulation configuration right way and emulator itself works as you expect. Anyway, you must configure a lot. It is much easier to use real device. My opinion is this case, that using emulator in this kind testing does not give you any benefit.